# eclipse RCP: plugin runs via popup-menu

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have created a non-RCP plugin project in `eclipse`. To run my eclipse plugin, the user must right clicks on a file and select my tool option from a popup menu. Is it possible to have a RCP for such a plugin? How can I provide a RCP distribution (zip) ready to be tested for such a plugin? Would you help me to find an appropriate manual for such a case?

Comment: An RCP is a complete program, not something you can add to an existing Eclipse. It sounds like you want a deployable plug-in or feature. Look at 'File > Export > Plug-in Development'

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for your comment. I have implemented my java plugin and created eclipse update site for it via plug-in development. Now, a reviewer told me "to ease the evaluation of the tool, I would recommend to provide a RCP distribution (zip) ready to be tested and not only the update site". As I'm new in RCP, I wonder whether what he/she means.

Comment: They probably mean package a complete Eclipse including your plugin.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks. Is there any specified way to create a package?

Comment: Most modern Eclipse distributions use the Oomph installer, I have no experience of using that. Personally I think a complete RCP is only useful if you have a lot of plug-ins - for example the Spring Tools Suite distribution.